# Get previous divs data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as follows

```
<tr><td>1st</td><td>Dennis wright</td><td><strong>334,000</strong> points</td></tr>

<tr><td>2nd</td><td>Matthew Smith</td><td><strong>41,046</strong> points</td></tr>

<tr><td>3rd</td><td>thomas jones</td><td><strong>15,783</strong> points</td></tr><tr><td>4th</td>
```

When I use

```
$( "tr:contains('Matthew Smith')" );
```

It returns

```
<tr><td>2nd</td><td>Matthew Smith</td><td><strong>41,046</strong> points</td></tr>
```

How can I query it so I can find the first td position (2nd in this case) and save as a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[`prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)** method in jQuery to get immediately preceding sibling

```js
var td = $("td:contains('Matthew Smith')").prev('td');

alert(td.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1st</td>
    <td>Dennis wright</td>
    <td><strong>334,000</strong> points</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2nd</td>
    <td>Matthew Smith</td>
    <td><strong>41,046</strong> points</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3rd</td>
    <td>thomas jones</td>
    <td><strong>15,783</strong> points</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rather find td that contains required text along with `.prev()` to target its previous td:

```
var targettd = $("td:contains('Matthew Smith')").prev();
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can use `.prev()`:

```
var rankTd = $("td:contains('Matthew Smith')").prev('td'); 
// returns the td but with jQuery wrapper.
```

and there is a method in javascript called ``:

```
var rankTd = $("td:contains('Matthew Smith')")[0].previousElementSibling; 
// returns the DOM node.
```

```js
var rankTd1 = $("td:contains(Matthew Smith)").prev('td');
var rankTd2 = $("td:contains(Matthew Smith)")[0].previousElementSibling;

console.log(".prev()", rankTd1);
console.log(".previousElementSibling", rankTd2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1st</td>
    <td>Dennis wright</td>
    <td><strong>334,000</strong> points</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>2nd</td>
    <td>Matthew Smith</td>
    <td><strong>41,046</strong> points</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>3rd</td>
    <td>thomas jones</td>
    <td><strong>15,783</strong> points</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```